# MVVM Repository Firebase data retrieved after the variable is set to null

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm

I am trying to implement the MVVM pattern in my project and i have a problem with the repository. When I try to get the data from Firebase, the **data** variable is already set to the initial value of **dataSet**. The data from Firebase is fetched correctly, but it comes to late.

```java
public class BikeRepository {
    private static BikeRepository instance;
    private ArrayList<Bike> dataSet = new ArrayList<Bike>();
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    public static BikeRepository getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BikeRepository();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Bike>> getBikes() {
        setBikes();
        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Bike>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        data.setValue(dataSet);
        System.out.println(dataSet);
        return data;
    }

    private void setBikes() {
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String owner = user.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.db_instance)).getReference("Users").child(owner).child("BikeCollection");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Bike bike = postSnapshot.getValue(Bike.class);
                    dataSet.add(bike);
                    System.out.println(dataSet.size());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "comes to late"? Are you referring to [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes. But I want to use onChildListener or onValueEventListener, not onSingleValueEventListener like in that solution

Comment: The solution is always the same, no matter what kind of listener are you using. If you understand Kotlin, then this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help.